# Настройка Github и PHPStorm

Tags: git, github, phpstorm

Как выполнять, commit в PHPStorm (или git bash без разницы), именно с профиля, который на Github? 
Сейчас получается, что все мои push и commit, выполняются от имени какого-то другого пользователя, которого я указываю в конфигах: `git config --global user.name "YOUR NAME"`. Парадоксально, что даже если имя будет совпадать с именем профиля Github, это будет все равно два разных пользователя. Как следствие один с аватаркой другой без неё.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никакого парадокса. Дело в электронной почте:

```
git config user.email адрес@е.почты
```

(Без `--global` настройки запомнятся в локальной копии репозитория, кстати.)

GitHub осторожничает с приписыванием коммитов к учётной записи, а потому использует для этого только подтверждённые адреса электронной почты. В коммите же фактически можно написать что угодно.

Comment: да я как раз читал - [тут](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/GitHub-%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8), но почту я тоже устанавливал такую же, буду пробывать

Comment: @dev.user По возможности, не пользуйтесь сокращателями ссылок. У нас такие ссылки часто принимают за спам и применяют *санкции*. :) У ссылок простой синтаксис: `[текст](адрес)`

Comment: ок), возвращаясь к вопросу вот добавил тот же email, который используется в профиле, но опять push и commit от другого пользователя.

Comment: @dev.user в `git log` адрес правильный? (Сначала разберёмся с коммитами, с пушами всё иначе)

Comment: в общем разобрался спасибо, у меня было два email в ~/.gitconfig, как вообще правильно ставить на нужный project, нужный конфигурации (user.name,user.email)? и как теперь удалить один из повторяющихся email, git как-то странно инициализирует их одним списком видимо.

Comment: @dev.user как правило, в глобальном держать самые частоиспользуемые, а в отдельных репозиториях указывать явно без `--global`, если в них отличаются.

Comment: так, а как на отдельный репозиторий указать config? просто если сделать `git config --list` он мне покажет одним списком все email и user

Comment: @dev.user Просто вносить настройки без `--global`, и они сохранятся в `./.git/config` (может отличаться, точно не помню, но его трудно пропустить).